# Numpy mean percentile range, eg. Mean (25th to 50th Percentile)?

Tags: python, numpy, percentile

I want to calculate the mean between two percentile ranges, For example between 25th and 50th percentile.

I normally use np.percentile to calculate specific percentile values.

Any idea how to calculate mean(25-50)? Can I subtract?

```
mean(25-50) = np.percentile(array,50) - np.percentile(array,25)
``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply subtract the two values at different percentile.

In order to find the mean of elements between 25th and 50th percentile, you need to find the sum of all of these elements and divide it by the size.

To find the sum of the elements mentioned above, you can subtract the sum of 0-25th percentile elements from the sum of 0-50th percentile.

Once you have the difference sum, just divide it by the size of those elements.

```py
# find the indexes of the element below 25th and 50th percentile
idx_under_25 = np.argwhere(array <= np.percentile(array, 25)).ravel()
idx_under_50 = np.argwhere(array <= np.percentile(array, 50)).ravel()

# find the number of the elements in between 25th and 50th percentile
diff_num = len(idx_under_50) - len(idx_under_25)

# find the sum difference
diff_sum = np.sum(np.take(array, idx_50)) - np.sum(np.take(array, idx_25))

# get the mean
mean = diff_sum / diff_num
```

Comment: The following one-liner also works for me (1D array): `mean = np.mean(array[np.logical_and(array > np.percentile(array, 25), array <= np.percentile(array, 50))])`